# File was build for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, opencv3.0

I've build OpenCV 3.2.0 with contrib for iOS. Everything works nice, but when I want to use the MultiTracker class (from libopencv_tracking) and run the project on a physical device i get this warning:

```
*Ignoring file /libopencv-tracking.dylib, file was build for x86_65 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64)*
```

Because the project can't be linked with the library, it can't find reference to that class, hence some errors.

If I run in a terminal 'lipo -info libopencv_tracking.3.2.dylib' i see that the architecture is x86_64 and i have no Idea why. I never explicitly set the architecture to be like this.

I really searched the last day and none of the answers helped me. Thank you!

Comment: When you built the library, you built it for OS X, possibly for the simulator, and not for the device.  You need to rebuild the library specifically for the device.

Comment: Yes, i get this, but i don't know where to explicitely say that i want this for the device and not for the mac os or the simulator. I tried to set CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES to armv7 but I get an error.